# StageOrientationEvent is not dispatching on DEFAULT orientation (Portrait)

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop

Intro:
I have a AIR Mobile AS3 Project, where I want to receive all Orientation events onChange, but never actually let the device rotate the Screen (I do the necessary altering myself). So I set the autoOrients=true (needed to get any Orientation events) and try to prevent the device rotation by e.preventDefault ([now deprecated on iOS](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/09/28/orientation-changes-in-air/)).

You can download a FlashDeveloper Project with the problem [here](http://www.file-upload.net/download-10671405/AirMobileAS3AppOrientationTest.zip.html).
Upload it to an Android device and let me know if you get StageOrientationEvents when rotating back to Default (Portrait).

The three other Orientations fire just fine and I receive from afterOrientation:

- rotatedRight
- rotatedLeft
- upsideDown

But when rotating back to the initial Position (Protrait) StageOrientationEvent does not fire.

My application.xml ist like this:

```
<visible>true</visible>
<fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
<autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
<aspectRatio>any</aspectRatio>
<resizable>true</resizable>
```

Interesting tho is, that when I start my App on Mobile in Landscape, I receive:

- rotatedLeft
- upsideDown
- default

So again, when rotating to the initial Position (in this case rotatedRight) StageOrientationEvent ist not firing. The Initial Position does not give a StageOrientationEvent.

This is my listener:

```
private function onOrientationChanging(e:StageOrientationEvent):void {

    e.preventDefault();

    ui.console.field.text += "\nORIENTATION_CHANGING "+e.afterOrientation;

    var rot:Number = 0;

    switch (e.afterOrientation){
        case "rotatedRight":
            rot = 90;
            break;

        case "rotatedLeft":
            rot = -90;;
            break;

        case "upsideDown":
            rot = 180;;
            break;
        default:
            rot = 0;
            break;

    }


    TweenMax.to(ui.console.orient, 3, { shortRotation:{rotationZ:rot}, ease:Elastic.easeOut } );

}
```

I even tried removing the e.preventDefault() in the hope that this somehow not only disabled the auto-rotation of the app but also somehow might prevent the firing of the default rotation. But that is not the case.

Any ideas?

Specs:

FlashDevelop 5.0

SDK Air17.0 + FLex 4.6.0

Android Nexus 5 Android 5.1.1

Comment: There are two events - orientation changing and orientation changed.  You are checking orientation changed inside a orientation changing listener.  Get rid of preventDefault.  Here is rotation code for ios and android mobile:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30293578/3661764

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned, that I want to receive OrientationChangeEvents, but dont want the device to rotate. From the Reference: _"The ORIENTATION_CHANGING event is dispatched as the application detects that a change is occurring and before any default behaviors such as auto-orientation (discussed later) actually occur. The ORIENTATION_CHANGE event occurs after any default orientation behaviors occur."_ So in my Case, I gotta use ORIENTATION_CHANGING to prevent the Device from rotating the Screen on OrientationChange. How do I get all OrientationChange Events firing, but never rotate?

Comment: I have added a demo FlashDeveloper Project link and as well reported this problem as a bug to the adobe Bugbase [here](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4002469).

Comment: Why aren't you using Accelerometer?  You can receive events for any movement.

Comment: Wouldnt that drain the battery kinda hard?

Comment: How does accelerometer drain the battery?  You have to use listeners for everything.

Comment: I were under the impression that having a 500ms setRequestedUpdateInterval Listener would keep the Gyro alive, and that could have inpact on the battery. But I was talking out of my ass. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863131/android-accelerometer-sensor-usage-and-power-consumption) is a SO Topic about that. I will give it a try. Thank you.