# StageWebView Rotation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have trouble finding a solution (if at all there is one) to rotate the StageWebView. I need this as I handle the Orientation in my App without autoOrient, therefore I need to rotate the StageWebView.

I tried StageWebViewBridge as well, but I also need the drawViewPortToBitmapData, wha is basicly the reason no ANE out there comes close to the vanilla StageWebView Solution.

I develop on Air for Android/iOS.

Any ideas?

Comment: you have created your own unsolvable problem. Don't handle yourself orientation and your problem will disappear.

Comment: Please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649092/stageorientationevent-is-not-dispatching-on-default-orientation-portrait). Thank you for Help.

Comment: still my comment applies. Why would you handle yourself the orientation and create all those problems for yourself? That's the part you never say. If there's no technical reasons behind it then you are just shooting yourself in teh foot.

Comment: Have you ever opened a modern Camera App on your Mobile Device and noticed that the camera in fact does not rotate but only the UI Elements? Thank you for your caring words.
EDIT: "Don't handle yourself orientation and your problem will disappear." as you can see from my link, that is not the case.

Comment: what link? Seems to me you would have better chances fixing the camera problem than fixing the numerous problems coming along with faking device orientation change.

Comment: Dont take it the wrong way, but I dont think you get it. I [linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649092/stageorientationevent-is-not-dispatching-on-default-orientation-portrait) already to the SO Topic about how OrientationEvent is broken in AIR17.0.0 and therefore I'm forced to use AccData for platform persistent Orientation. 18.0.0 still has the Bug. Thank you for your Time, but none of your last comments was in any way helpful. Please end it here.

Comment: I get it just fine, facing one problem you decided to go one way but that way doesn't work and never will. Yet you don't want to accept it and instead you gonna waste days, weeks, months trying to make it work until finally you will give up and do basically what I said here. Can't wish you good luck cos luck won't help here.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to any transformations with `StageWebView`.
Why you dont use the `HTMLLoader`-class? It is a normal `DisplayObject` and can be rotated, filtered and so on...

Comment: "This feature is supported on all desktop operating systems, but is not supported on mobile devices or on AIR for TV devices. You can test for support at run time using the HTMLLoader.isSupported property." [source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html)

Comment: Ok. I didnt know... Then there is no way.